# Android Interface Webview

Tags: android, interface, webview

I want to create an interface for my project that has a button and when the button is clicked it begins the activity from another java file which is a library but am having some difficulty. The referenced java file opens a webview. Here is what I have

```
    package com.dcu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.news.*;

public class DCU extends Activity 
{
    private Button somebutton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initControls();
    }
    protected void initControls()
    {
        somebutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.News);
        somebutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        { 
            public void onClick (View v)
            { 
                News n = new News();
                n.onCreate(null);
            }
        });
}
```

}

Then I have a main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:text="Button" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="news" android:id="@+id/News"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

And news.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Here is the News.java

```
package com.news;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class News extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    String test2 = "<html><body><table border='0'>";
    Document docs;
    Document writing;

    String text(String link)
    {
        String full ="<html><body><table border='0'><tr><td align ='center'>";;
        try {
             writing = Jsoup.connect(link).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements classname = writing.getElementsByClass("news");
        Element heading = classname.select("h2").first();
        Elements items = classname.select("p");

        full = full + "<h1>" + heading.text()+ "</h1>" + "<h2>" + items.get(0).toString() + "</h1>" + "</td></tr>";
        Element imgs2 = writing.select("div.News img").first();

        String picture = imgs2.absUrl("src");
        String newImg = "<img src=\"" + picture + "\" width = '450' align = 'center'>";
        full = full + "<tr><td align='center'>" + newImg + "</td></tr>";
        full = full + "<tr><td><h1>";

        for (int i = 1; i< items.size(); i++)
        {
            full = full + items.get(i).toString();
        }

        full = full + "</h1></td></tr></table></body></html>";
        return full;
    }
    public void main(String... args) 
    {
        try 
        {
             docs = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dcu.ie/news/index.shtml").get();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements imgs = docs.select("div.news-feature img");

        Elements txt = docs.select("h2");

        Elements article = docs.getElementsByClass("date");
        Elements links = article.select("a[href]");

        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.size(); i++){
            String url = imgs.get(i).absUrl("src");
            String temp = links.get(i).absUrl("href");

            String temp2 = "<a href=\"" + temp + "\">";
            String newImg = temp2 + "<img src=\"" + url + "\" align = 'center' width = '300'>"+ "</a>";
            test2 = test2 + "<tr>";

            test2 = test2 + "<td>";
            test2 = test2 + " " + newImg + " ";
            test2 = test2 + "</td>";
            test2 = test2 + "<td>";
            test2 = test2 + "<h1>" + txt.get(i).text() + "</h1>";
            test2 = test2 + "</td>";
            test2 = test2 + "</tr>";

            }
        test2 = test2 + "</table>";
        test2 = test2 + "</html></body>";

    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        main();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main );

        // Makes Progress bar Visible
        getWindow().setFeatureInt( Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new NewsClient());
        mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadData(test2, "text/html", "utf-8");

        final Activity MyActivity = this;
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)  
         {
          //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes string to Loading...
          MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
          MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

          // Return the app name after finish loading
             if(progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
           }
         });

        //mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        //mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", test2,"text/html", "utf-8", "");

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) 
        {
            mWebView.goBack();          
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class NewsClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (view.canGoBack() == false)
            {
                String newUrl = text(url);
                view.loadData(newUrl, "text/html", "utf-8");
            }
            else
            {
                view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            //view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", newUrl,"text/html", "utf-8", "");

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a Intent to start your activity. Instead of:

```
News n = new News();
n.onCreate(null);
```

Use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(DCU.this, News.class);
DCU.this.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I still get a force close message when I click the button